# Re-use domain after years of 301 redirect

Tags: seo, redirects, 301-redirect

I want to use a top level domain for a new website. I registered the domain many years ago, but never used it before.

I just redirected the domain after registering many years ago via 301 reditect to another website from me.

Now I want to use the domain for a new website. Can the 301 redirect in the past affect the ranking of the website in the future?

Comment: First ask yourself, does the old domain have any weight? There is no meaning of using two empty buckets, no matter how much old they are. If your old domains have some links to it, then 301 redirection may help you to any website on which you're doing 301 redirection, but once you cut the line i.e. remove the 301 redirection, and point to y website, then y domain will get benefits. Google follow redirection just like our browser do.

Answer (score 1):

> Can the 301 redirect in the past affect the ranking of the website in the future?

No, assuming you are just adding the site to your search engine.

Remember 301 redirects are cached in your browser and only cached for a few days.

Comment: I would clarify that you are answering "No" to the question raised in the very last sentence of the question and not the question title, as it looks to the casual glance.

Comment: @w3dk the post has been updated, thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Since it will be directed to something entirely different, yes. Cause it's entirely different content, I assume.